# Add https enforcement to a second domain in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# Use PHP56
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^directoryhub\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.directoryhub.net [R,L]
```

This redirects `directoryhub.net`, which is my root domain in `public_html`, to https.

However, now I want to do the same thing with a second domain (all the files of which are in a subfolder of `public_html`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your second domain pointing to the `/subfolder` meaning that when you type `seconddomain.com` do you see the `/subfolder`  page ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hardcoded host name in condition and target to make it generic for all the domains that are controlled by your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I changed my .htaccess file to this but it's not working. Do I need to clear my browser cache?

Comment: Yes cache should be cleared. Make sure this is top rule and there is no other .htaccess on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was editing the `.htaccess` file in the root folder, which is the wrong file. I needed to edit the `.htaccess` file within `public_html` as well as the `.htaccess` file within each of my subdomains to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I suppose I could also delete all the `.htaccess` files of my subdomains and change the root `.htaccess` to @anubhava's answer, but it works by editing each individual file as well.